# Keras/TF trained model works as Django app once, then returns value errors

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

TF community --

So I have trained a TensorFlow model using simple MNIST data. I'm using Keras' `load_model` in a Python script to pull it up and `model.predict()`  to feed images to the model (once the data is properly transformed) so it can make predictions. This works well when running `predict.py` from the command line with various examples.

But my goal is to web app-ify this prediction script so I can ping it from other apps. It was fairly easy to spin up a Django app and cause `predict.py` to run whenever a certain URL endpoint was hit. Given a random MNIST image sent in a POST request, the app will (usually correctly) make a prediction the first time, which I can see in the server logs in square brackets:

`2018-02-09 17:49:40.639847: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow d
evice (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
[5]
[09/Feb/2018 17:49:43] "POST /predict/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1`

Then, without fail, all subsequent posts generate errors until I restart the server with `python manage.py runserver`. I usually get several overlapping exceptions to this where it doesn't like various some placeholder values - but to my knowledge I'm never setting that stuff - it's all Keras, right?

`ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_2:0", shape=(3, 3, 32, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.`

Here's the script - it's very simple. For the sake of argument I am even removing the web request image, and just trying to run predictions on the same locally-stored image. Again, works once, then errors:

`def index(request):
    model = load_model('C:\\Users\\james\\PycharmProjects\\karas-test\\my_model.h5')
    # get image out  of request object
    im = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\james\\PycharmProjects\\karas-test\\5.png",0)
    # cv2.imshow('ImageWindow', im)
    # cv2.waitKey()
    im = im/255
    im = numpy.expand_dims(im, axis=0)
    probs = model.predict(im.reshape(1,28,28,1), 1)
    prediction = probs.argmax(axis=-1)
    print(prediction)
    return HttpResponse(prediction)`

Am I failing to properly unload or destroy some object or data file before the return value? Do I only need to load the model or spin up the GFX card for TensorFlow once on app/server start?

Confusing! Any help appreciated. Thanks, all!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should only load the model once.  I'm not entirely clear how Keras handles things, but in basic TensorFlow what you're doing would create multiple copies of the model in your default graph, and add something like `_2` to the variable names so they're unique.  I think something along those lines is happening here.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right! One thing that has worked as a quick fix was to `import keras.backend as K` then `K.clear_session()` at the end of the request. I'm an ML noob, you think that would have the effect of removing the model from the default graph or no? Even though it works,  seems inefficient. Judging from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871516/correctly-loading-keras-model-in-django-that-supports-multi-tenancy) and [this Django issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2397#issuecomment-254919212), you're correct that I need only load the model once.

Comment: You're right about `clear_session`, although technically it deletes the default graph and creates a new one.  Definitely a useful tool to have.  And yes, loading a model is not a trivial operation, especially since it's reading from a file each time, so you should avoid doing it per request.